# Is Docker an alternative for 'virtualenv' while develping Django project?

Tags: python, django, docker, containers, virtualenv

A virtual environment is required when creating an application and now I am using 'virtualenv' for creating a virtual environment while developing my Django application. I heard of Docker about its virtual environment. Am I able to use Docker as an alternative to virtualenv?

Answer (score 5):

Managing Python versions and dependencies with `virtualenv` (or `pipenv`) will likely be your method of choice for your app running on `localhost`.

You can of course run your app exclusively in a Docker container, where you won't have the need for any separate environments and will manage dependencies via the `Dockerfile` (and perhaps `pip`).

I'd suggest the following approach: run an instance of your app on `localhost` and simultaneously a production version in a Docker container. Also, run your database in a Docker container alongside (both managed via `docker-compose`.)

For a detailed walk-through on how to set this up (shameless plug), see [this post](https://medium.com/faun/tech-edition-how-to-dockerize-a-django-web-app-elegantly-924c0b83575d) or this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/hendrikfrentrup/docker-django)

Answer (score 3):

While in practice, you *could*, you really shouldn't. Docker should in most cases be a method of distribution, rather than a way of isolating your development environment. That is to say that your final product -- the Django project you produce -- could be distributed as a docker image so it's easily deployed (and scaled via Kubernetes), but distributing an image just to handle the development environment is definitely nonstandard and I wouldn't recommend it.

Instead, consider [Pipenv](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which neatly combines `pip` and `venv` into a human-digestible package. Store all that in your code repository, and setting up a development environment is as simple as

```
git clone
pipenv install --dev
```

Comment: Using Docker images to manage dependencies (and even distribute those) is a great way to avoid the usual "Works on my machine" issue - especially working in a team. The `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` are great places to implement infrastructure-as-code

Comment: @HendrikF agreed, but typically _not_ for active development. That's what `requirements.txt` and `venv` are for. Otherwise you've gotta start installing IDEs in your docker, or bind-mounting and pointing your IDE at a weird interpreter that lives inside the container.... No reason for any of that nonsense.

Comment: There are plenty of reasons to choose docker instead of a virtualenv that can differ between projects. All of the major IDEs have great built in support for development using docker. I'd hardly call it nonsense and would argue it is becoming standard

Comment: If you can argue that is is "becoming standard," it admits then that it's a nonstandard approach. I would consider good practice to be producing a docker image as a build artifact. Using it solely to create a Python environment seems wrong-headed. Ultimately, though, docker and venv are both about creating isolated environments to prevent "works on my machine" issues. If you're accomplishing that goal, whatever means you use to do it is fine _I guess_ :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes docker can be used as an alternative.

virtualenv just sets a fresh python installation in path which can be used to install dependencies particular to your project without polluting global python installation and thus managing versioning as well.

Docker is a step further and gives a complete OS - linux image and OS level isolation. Not just one can have a isolated python installation but can also have other os specific dependencies installed like ffmpeg, lapack, arpack etc. A new developer can spin up a container from docker image having all dependencies (python and OS) installed.

Answer (score 1):

The usage of virtualenv or docker depends on your requirement or use case.

Docker container encapsulates an entire OS and provides isolation of OS whereas a virtualenv only encapsulates Python dependencies which enables switching between Python versions and dependencies, but you are dependent with your host OS.

Virtualenv can be used in case if you have two different projects on your machine that require two different versions of the same package with python. Typically, the virtualenv provides abstraction from OS's use of python.

Docker enables portability from one machine to another whereas with virtualenv you will have to do the installation in another place.  Docker isolates all of the additional system dependencies too and provides a completely isolated environment.  It is containerization platform which is used to package your application and all its dependencies together in the form of containers so to make sure that your application works seamlessly in any environment which can be development or test or production. It helps to ensure that the Dev and Production environment are completely same.

Answer (score 0):

DOCKERFILE

```
FROM python:3.9
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

DOCKER-COMPOSE

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
        - "8000:8000"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).